# Add Style to a recently added Plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, styling

I'm getting crazy with a plugin I recently added to my theme: Kupon from Themeforest.

It's about the Woocommerce Radio Buttons Plugin – https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-radio-buttons/

Does any of you guys know how to edit the plugin to let me style it in my way?

It seems that there is no class added, so I'm unable to edit the styles of that class.

How can I modify the plugin that lets me style it similar to this site: http://design.savnpik.com/abu-dhabi-deals/spa-beauty/dazzle-ladies-beauty-saloon-offer/

The current output on my site can be found here: http://mrvoucher.de/produkt/haarschnitt-rasur-bei-baba-barbier-langenfeld/

Comment: Could you paste in your question the generated HTML for the radio, including the previous label?

Comment: Sorry dont understand your question, where can i find that files ?

Comment: Just look for the source code in your browser when you're on the product page (ctrl + u), and paste the part of HTML related to those buttons (radio + label). Or if you can share the URL of the product page.

Comment: Is there a class that wraps only radios you want to style? If so you can always do it with `.wrapper input[type="radio"]` and leave a note in the CSS saying that, in the future, that might select too much.

Comment: of course i can share. here is the page with the Variations set up

http://mrvoucher.de/produkt/haarschnitt-rasur-bei-baba-barbier-langenfeld/

Page is German, i would like to use the variations for Vouchers with different values. but the style looks so poor

Comment: i would like to have it look like this:

http://design.savnpik.com/abu-dhabi-deals/spa-beauty/dazzle-ladies-beauty-saloon-offer/

This site use the same theme, but with a nice looking style

Comment: The plugin is going to have to be edited in some way. To do what Patrick wants requires additional tags not present in the plugin's default output- otherwise you're styling `<br>`s and doing weird pixel-perfect mouseover calculations.

Comment: The Radio Buttons plugin hasn't been updated in ages. I tried, but eventually gave up as it wasn't worth the effort. You are probably going to have an easier time using [Variation Swatches and Images](https://www.woothemes.com/products/variation-swatches-and-photos/).

Comment: #helgathevikink you made my day... a better solution instead of my first choice. Thanks for Sharing. This Topic can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class of "variations" on the overall wrapper for your buttons. Just do `.variations input[type="radio"]` (or `.variations .value input` to support browsers that don't support attribute selectors with minimal false-positives) to target the radio buttons to style them.

Comment: Dear its not just about adding style to the Radio Button himself. my goal is to style it the same way like: http://design.savnpik.com/abu-dhabi-deals/spa-beauty/dazzle-ladies-beauty-saloon-offer/ they do the job.

Compare and you will see what i mean. Thanks for your Time.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't do it using the suggestion I gave. I would be able to if I tried.